# TikZ: Track the bounding rectangle of created nodes (Storing values?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, key-value

In the main part of the `tikzpicture` I'd like to simply create `block`s. So I need somewhere in theirs' style definition to perform tracking of their common bounding rectangle. I've tried to access `current bounding box`, but it is obviously set to node's rectangle, thus, unfortunately, duplicating the `path picture bounding box`.

I'm going to use this box when creating another type of nodes (say, `foo`, which is to be implemented shortly). So, again, it should be accessible from inside `foo`'s style definition. The goal is to make this calculations invisible from the user (drawer) perspective, though he will be restricted to declare nodes in two consecutive sections.

Is there a way to do this task in a somewhat more comfortable way than writing it with low-level commands, such as `ifdim`, etc.? What is preferred way of storing values, when drawing with TikZ? I guess, this is not by using `\newcommand`, which defines macros available at global scope. Up to now I've managed to store values using `\pgfkeys` but I stuck at getting the main picture's bounding box.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,chains,shapes.multipart,backgrounds,positioning,fit,calc}

\newcommand{\setup}{
    \tikzset{
        node distance=5mm and 3cm,
        block/.style={rectangle, %draw, thick,
            path picture={
                \draw[red, thick] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
            }
        },
        %foo/.style={circle},
        every edge/.style={->, rounded corners, thick, draw,
            to path={
                let \p1=(\tikztostart.east),
                    \p2=($ (\tikztostart.east) + (1cm,0) $),
                    \p3=(\tikztotarget.west) in
                (\p1) -- (\p2) \ifdim\y2=\y3  -- \else |- \fi (\p3)
                \tikztonodes
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \setup

    % First section. This blocks will build up the bounding rectangle, which is to be used in the next section.
    \node[block=1] (A) {System A};
    \node[block=2] (B) [above right=of A] {System B};
    \node[block=3] (C) [right=of A] {System C};
    \node[block=4] (D) [below right=of A] {System D};

    % Second section. Positioning of this nodes depends on the resulting bounding rectangle of the previous section.
    %\node[foo] (o1) {circle 1};
    %\node[foo] (o2) {circle 2};

    \path
    (A) edge (B)
        edge (C)
        edge (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: *`\newcommand`, which defines macros available at global scope*: No, `\newcommand` defines macros in the local scope, not globally. You can also use `\def\macroname{...}` to store content.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I've played more with nodes and styles...
The conclusion that inside `path picture` the `current bounding box` duplicates `path picture bounding box` was completely false. It stands what it should for. So, this code works (thanks to global definition of nodes):

```
block/.style={rectangle,
    path picture={
        \node[rectangle, fit=(current bounding box), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (my bounding box) {};
    }
},
```

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to figure out, why in the example of the initial post each node gets surrounded by red border while that red border should increase in size with the creation of each new node.

Comment: -1 It seems unfair that you answered your own question using `fit` library suggestion given in an answer by Martin Scharrer and then accepted your answer. You also state that your own answer is incomplete. Perhaps your original question was unclear.

Comment: @ipavlic: Though Martin's answer uses approach, which is also based on `fit` library, it doesn't solve the problem arised. So, I considered it to be superficial. Thanks for your critics.

Answer (score 8):

The `fit` library of TikZ can be used to create a surrounding rectangle or other shaped node of multiple nodes or coordinates.

```
% Preamble:
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
% ..
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,fit=(a) (b) (c) (d) (e)] (bb) {};
% use `(bb.north west)` etc. to access the boundaries
```

> What is prefered way of storing values, when drawing with TikZ?

You can use `coordinate (<name>)` inside a `\path` to save the current position.
Alternative there is the `\coordinate (<name>) at (<coordinate>);` macro.

Comment: +1 on the preferred way.  With TikZ you rarely have to work with dimensions and coordinates directly; you can use nodes and libraries for maximum flexibility.

Comment: I agree with you. the `fit library` is the fine method here

Comment: Before posting here, I've investigated pgfmanual. So I'm aware of the `fit` library. @Martins's code snippet allows to get boundary box, but - as far as I understand --- only after all nodes have been created. And this bounding box node should be created manually after defining `block`s (in my case). But I want it to be implicitly calculated, and, more over, then used while creating another type of nodes.

Comment: Using `fit` style I have to redefine node `bb` (inside `block/.style`) as `\node[...,fit=(current bounding box) (bb)] (bb) {};`. I am afraid of such recrusive redifinition, at least when doing this for the first time, when there's no such node `bb` by the moment.

Comment: @Dmitry: The only nodes which must be already created for `fit` are the nodes use in the fit. You can define more nodes afterwards. You could try to use the `every node` key to recreate your bounding box node using `fit` every time a new node is created.

Comment: @Dmitry: The `current bounding box` will always include `bb` and all nodes, so your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Martin: I implied that code be inside the: `block/.style={..., path picture={ <here> }}`.

Comment: @Dmitry: I assume the `current bounding box` node is not yet updated at this point? However it will include all paths drawn before the node, and so for I understand it this isn't what you want.

Comment: @Martin: In the first paragraph of my initial post I wrote: "I've tried to access `current bounding box`, but it is obviously set to node's rectangle, thus, unfortunately, duplicating the `path picture bounding box`". If you compile code snippet from that post, you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Dmitry: No I actually don't. Your whole first paragraph isn't very understandable to me. Compiling the code doesn't help much either. I still don't know what you actually require. Do you want to have the bounding box which only includes certain nodes without any other paths or not? What do you mean exactly with "I'd like to simply create blocks.". If you want to simply draw red outlines around the nodes use the `draw=red` style. See also the `local bounding box` option in the `pgfmanual` p.624.

Comment: @ Martin: Yes, I want it to include only certain type of nodes. I've read about `local bounding box` and it doesn't feet my needs.