# TikZ: Rectangle spanning a submatrix, as a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I specify the corners of a rectangle, spanning a certain submatrix of a matrix, and want this rectangle to be a node. The minimal example is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{scopes,arrows,calc,shapes.misc,shapes.arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\bbrect}[2]{\draw (B-#1-2.north west) rectangle (B-#2-2.south east)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \ttfamily
    \matrix (B) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement = \&] {
        \hline
        {0} \& {12}\\
        {1} \& {7}\\
        {2} \& {2}\\
        {3} \& {2}\\
        {} \& {2}\\
        {} \& {2}\\
        {} \& {2}\\
        {} \& {2}\\
        };
    \bbrect{1}{1};
    \bbrect{2}{2};
    \bbrect{3}{8};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of problem in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15148/7049. Answer is equivalent.

Comment: Is it possible to give the reason why you want it to be a node? Since matrix is filled with nodes it is relatively easy to access the to-be-drawn rectangle coordinates with matrix entry anchors.

Comment: Nodes in a submatrix can be very useful for later use, for example for arrows and annotations. Like here: [Highlighting while transposing a matrix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40333/213).

Comment: @percusse: it is to convey the idea that the contiguous group of "2"s collapse into one group, etc. I'll have another, "merged" version on the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `fit` library. Specify `rectangle` and `draw` option, the points spanning the rectangle, and `inner sep=0` for tight fitting:

```
\newcommand{\bbrect}[2]{%
  \node[rectangle, draw, fit=(B-#1-2.north west) (B-#2-2.south east),
  inner sep=0pt] {}}
```

With your code, this adds to your `\hline` the desired rectangles:

[image: fitting rectangles in matrix]

Comment: That will not work, though, if one of the nodes in the middle is wider.  For example, if the 2 on the right of 3 is changed into 222, it will stick out of the rectangle.

Comment: @JanHlavacek: That's true, in this case that node can be added to the fitting. However, the point of the question was turning the rectangle into a node, this has been answered.

Comment: Yes, there are at most 2-digit number is my matrix :) Now how to put another "merged" matrix to the right of the existing one? so that to show how the contiguous groups collapsed into one-element entries...

Comment: @Ilonpilaaja: I suggest, write a new question on the site for the new question. Otherwise it's hard to put answers and code into comments, and it would mix topics. This is a Q&A site, other readers shall benefit too, that's why the strict Question & Answer structure, no topic discussions in comments.

Comment: Thanks all. This site is good at preserving the succinctness on the web; I was able to find the answer in one of the prompts that the Exchange suggested: the scopes + [xshift = 3cm] is the way to go.